# Cannot connect MongoDB Atlas from a newly created Spring Boot app with a connection string

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have just created a new Spring Boot app with this maven dependency:

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
```

And as also suggested from the Mongodb documentation, I have added this connection string line in my application.properties file (suggested String for Java Driver version 3.6 or later):

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://username:<password>@mynewcluster-0qpvv.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

When I login MongoDB Atlas in Database Access part I have created a new MongoDB user with this mongoDB role: **readWriteAnyDatabase@admin**.

Also when I go in Network Access, there is just a one IP address, which should allow any incoming ip addresses: 0.0.0.0/0.

I still cannot connect to db, and a simple query to db gives me this error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'bad auth Authentication failed.' on server mynewcluster-shard-00-01-0qpvv.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "bad auth Authentication failed.", "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError"}
```

I have also looked for similar problems here, mostly people had problems with their password. My password does not contain any special characters which needs encoding.. actually it is an auto generated password from Mongo Atlas's Database Access page and seems like this: tD6xuzYm3ZquzgTo.

What should I do more in order to connect to database?

Some people also suggested to define the database explicitly in applications properties like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydb
```

And create this db in Cluster->Collections->Create Database. But it did not change anything.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using <password>?  should be without < >

Comment: yes it was the reason :/  if your write that as an answer I will accept that. thank you!!